# Use both event_pages and background pages in a single chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

Changing background page to event_page makes the js script to be non-persistant. This can be done by following settings in manifest.json file:

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["eventPage.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
```

I wanted to know, is it possible to categorize certain js script files as event_page and few other js script files as background page in same chrome extension? If yes, how to do it?

Comment: If you are going to have some JavaScript code which is persistent, why do you want some which are not? In other words, what is your use case?

Comment: @Makyen, I'm planning a structure where background script calls a particular event_page script for a certain action whenever it is required. All js event scripts are not required to be present all the time in browser's memory. I believe this would improve performace of the extension.

Comment: You can probably imitate it by using iframes inside the background page DOM with src attribute pointing to those different "component" scripts. Removing an iframe would force garbage collection on its execution context. However, I'm not sure it'll be faster and more efficient than having a single big non-persistent event page script. Maybe it's better to redesign the workflow.